# How to get the longest and the shorted edge of a room boundary?

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

In the Revit API, I'm trying to get the longest and the shortest edge of a room boundary. (room is a rectangle)

For now, I have a list of 4 bounding edges of a room.(rb_curves) These are curves. I'm trying to sort this list by the length of each curve.

**sorted_rb_curves = sorted(rb_curves, key=?)**

I'm wondering what I can assign to the 'key' in order to sort.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to sort lists based on object attributes is using lambda. In your case it would be:

```
rb_curves.sort(key=lambda x: x.Length)
```

where `Length` is the attribute you are sorting by. Note this modifies your original list (as opposed to creating a new sorted list)

This would mean `rb_curves[0]` is the shortest Boundary, `rb_curves[-1]` is the longest.

Comment: perfect, love it.

Comment: Thanks so much! Cleaner and faster way to do it!